# Inverting a dictionary with list values

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, inverted-index

I have this index as a dict.

```
index = {
    'Testfil2.txt': ['nisse', 'hue', 'abe', 'pind'],
    'Testfil1.txt': ['hue', 'abe', 'tosse', 'svend']}
```

I need to invert the index so it will be a dict with duplicates of values merged into one key with the 2 original keys as values, like this:

```
inverse = {
    'nisse': ['Testfil2.txt'],
    'hue': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
    'abe': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
    'pind': ['Testfil2.txt'], 
    'tosse': ['Testfil1.txt'],
    'svend': ['Testfil1.txt']}
```

My textbook has this function for inverting dictionaries:

```
def invert_dict(d): 
    inverse = dict() 
    for key in d: 
        val = d[key] 
        if val not in inverse: 
            inverse[val] = [key] 
        else: 
            inverse[val].append(key) 
    return inverse
```

It works fine for simple key:value pairs, BUT, when I try that function with a dict that has lists as values such as my `index`, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#153>", line 1, in <module>
    invert_dict(index)
  File "<pyshell#150>", line 5, in invert_dict
    if val not in inverse:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The book is no help, and I suspect that I can use tuples in some way, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've tried around and you want to use `val not in inverse` but it can't be checked if a "list is in a dict". (`val` is a list)

For your code a simple change will do what you want:

```
def invert_dict(d): 
    inverse = dict() 
    for key in d: 
        # Go through the list that is saved in the dict:
        for item in d[key]:
            # Check if in the inverted dict the key exists
            if item not in inverse: 
                # If not create a new list
                inverse[item] = [key] 
            else: 
                inverse[item].append(key) 
    return inverse
```

Answer (score 29):

My solution for reversing a dictionary.

```
inverse = {}
for k,v in index.items():
    for x in v:
        inverse.setdefault(x, []).append(k)
```

Output:

```
{'nisse': ['Testfil2.txt'],
 'hue': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
 'abe': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
 'pind': ['Testfil2.txt'],
 'tosse': ['Testfil1.txt'],
 'svend': ['Testfil1.txt']}
```

Comment: FYI, the whole `try`/`except` nonsense could be shortened significantly by either making `new_dic` a `collections.defaultdict(list)` or with a plain `dict`, replacing the entire `try`/`except` with just `new_dic.setdefault(x, []).append(k)`, avoiding the need to handle "key exists" and "key missing" separately.

Answer (score 5):

As a nested comprehension:

```
inverse = { v: k for k, l in index.items() for v in l }
```

or, perhaps more clearly:

```
inverse = { 
            new_key: index_key                              #body
            for index_key, index_value in index.items()     #outer loop
                for new_key in index_value                  #inner loop
            }
```

which is roughly equivalent to:

```
new_keys    =   []
new_values  =   []

for index_key, index_value in index.items():
    for new_key in index_value:
        new_keys.append(new_key)
        new_values.append(index_key)
        
inverse     =   dict(zip(new_keys,new_values))
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic version. 1 line.

Comment: This does not work for OP's specified input. The values in the inverted dict need to be lists as well, in case there are elements common to multiple value-lists in the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `list` objects as dictionary keys, since they should be hashable objects. You can loop over your items and use `dict.setdefault` method to create the expected result:

```
new = {}
for k,value in index.items():
    for v in value:
        new.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Result:

```
{'nisse': ['Testfil2.txt'],
 'hue': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
 'abe': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
 'pind': ['Testfil2.txt'],
 'tosse': ['Testfil1.txt'],
 'svend': ['Testfil1.txt']}
```

and if you are dealing with larger datasets for refusing of calling creating an empty list at each calling the `setdefault()` method you can use `collections.defaultdict()` which will calls the missing function just when it encounter a new key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

new = defaultdict(list)
for k,value in index.items():
    for v in value:
        new[v].append(k)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
    {'nisse': ['Testfil2.txt'],
     'hue': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
     'abe': ['Testfil2.txt', 'Testfil1.txt'],
     'pind': ['Testfil2.txt'],
     'tosse': ['Testfil1.txt'],
     'svend': ['Testfil1.txt']})
```

Comment: Do you actually get a performance improvement with `defaultdict`? From what I remember from a related discussion, it's implemented in Python which makes it pretty slow while `dict.setdefault` is implemented in C and the time to create a new empty list is negligible.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a variation that uses a comprehension plus `set` to remove duplicates.

```python
def invert_setdict(setdict):
    inverse = {}
    vk = [(v, k) for k, vs in index.items() for v in vs]
    for k, v in vk:
       inverse.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)

    return inverse
```

Example

```
>>> index = {
... 'Testfil2.txt': ['nisse', 'hue', 'abe', 'pind'],
... 'Testfil1.txt': ['hue', 'abe', 'tosse', 'svend']}

>>> inverse = invert_setdict(index)
>>> inverse
{'nisse': {'Testfil2.txt'},
 'hue': {'Testfil1.txt', 'Testfil2.txt'},
 'abe': {'Testfil1.txt', 'Testfil2.txt'},
 'pind': {'Testfil2.txt'},
 'tosse': {'Testfil1.txt'},
 'svend': {'Testfil1.txt'}}
```

If you want to convert the set values to lists:

```python
>>> inverse = {k:list(v) for k, v in inverse.items()}
```

Comment: Remove duplicates? But OP's data doesn't have any duplicates... Neither does the data you're showing here... If this is filling a different need, you could post a separate question.

Comment: Note that sets are unordered. (And going back to lists doesn't restore the order.) If you want to preserve order, you can use a dict with `None` values as an ordered set.

Comment: There's no need to create `vk`; all it does is take up space. You can put its two loops directly in your code, just like in [Arman's answer](/a/35491335/4518341)

Answer (score -2):

Two liner solution using unpacking operator `*` and nested compression.

```
for k,v in old_dict.items():
    new_dict = {**new_dict,**{vi:k for vi in v}}
```

Comment: This has the same issue as Jeremy's answer, and also requires `new_dict = {}` to be initialized first.