# How do I reverse this dictionary in the format given?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert this:

```
d={'move': ['liikuttaa'], 'hide': ['piilottaa', 'salata'], 'six': ['kuusi'], 'fir': ['kuusi']}
```

into this:

```
{'liikuttaa': ['move'], 'piilottaa': ['hide'], 'salata': ['hide'], 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```

Basically reversing this dictionary. Also the values of the new dictionary should be in list form like shown.

I have already tried using the zip function, reversing through (v,k) but everytime I get the same error: "unhashable type list".

```
def reverse_dictionary(d):    
    reverse=list(zip(d.values(),d.keys()))
    return reverse
```

Output should be this:

```
{'liikuttaa': ['move'], 'piilottaa': ['hide'], 'salata': ['hide'], 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```

Comment: There's probably a one liner that can do this, but I'd rather write a loop.

Comment: notice that you don't have `'liikuttaa'` in the original dict, but rather you have `['liikuttaa']`. Essentially, it's a list. does a dictionary allow a list as keys? (ps. the answer is no. that's the error you see)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverting a dictionary with list values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491223/inverting-a-dictionary-with-list-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

d = {'move': ['liikuttaa'],
     'hide': ['piilottaa', 'salata'],
     'six': ['kuusi'],
     'fir': ['kuusi']}

result = defaultdict(list)

for key, values in d.items():
    for value in values:
        result[value].append(key)

pprint(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
{'kuusi': ['fir', 'six'],
 'liikuttaa': ['move'],
 'piilottaa': ['hide'],
 'salata': ['hide']}
```

Or you can use a normal `dict` with [**`setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
result = {}

for key, values in d.items():
    for value in values:
        result.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This one's perfect. Didn't try the first one one but the latter works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I would first create a generator that generators key, values pairs in the existing dictionary:

```
def pairs(d):
    for key in d:
        for value in d[key]:
            yield key, value
```

Then use defaultdict to create the reversed structure:

```
from collections import defaultdict
reversed_d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in pairs(d):
    reversed_d[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested list comprehension will do this:

```
{vv: k for k, v in d.items() for vv in v}
```

**Edit**

I misunderstood your requirement. This is better:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items()
    for val in v:
        new_dict[k].append(v)
```

Comment: This doesn't create list values for duplicate keys.

Comment: Works! But how do I make sure that the values of the new dictionary are in a list form enclosed with [ ] ?. Just like the values in the original dictionary 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple, dictionary reversing. You also need to access/create the inner list and populate it accordingly (while avoiding key clashing on the resulting dict).

One way of doing this is:

```
def reverse_dict_special(d):
    result = {}
    for k, vs in d.items():
        for v in vs:
            if v in result:
                result[v].append(k)
            else:
                result[v] = [k]
    return result

d = {'move': ['liikuttaa'], 'hide': ['piilottaa', 'salata'], 'six': ['kuusi'], 'fir': ['kuusi']}
reverse_dict_special(d)
# {'liikuttaa': ['move'],
#  'piilottaa': ['hide'],
#  'salata': ['hide'],
#  'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```

Note that this does not require the use of `collections.defaultdict`or using `dict.setdefault()` as proposed by @PeterWood.
Indeed the proposed method seems to get to faster results then both the other two:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def reverse_dict_special2(d):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key, values in d.items():
        for value in values:
            result[value].append(key)
    return result


def reverse_dict_special3(d):
    result = {}
    for key, values in d.items():
        for value in values:
            result.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    return result


%timeit reverse_dict_special(d)
# 1.22 µs ± 29.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit reverse_dict_special2(d)
# 2.04 µs ± 44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit reverse_dict_special3(d)
# 1.55 µs ± 18.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

(*EDITED*: I had misunderstood the question at first, and did not realize that the input inner lists may have had multiple items)

Comment: Not returning any value for 'salata'.

Comment: @TheVaibhavJ You are right, I had misunderstood the question in my first answer. Now it should be OK.