# How do I classify words in list according to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary with keys being a category name and values being words within that category. For example:

```
words={
    'seasons':('summer','spring','autumn','winter'),
    'rooms':('kitchen','loo','livingroom','hall','diningroom','bedroom'),
    'insects':('bee','butterfly','beetle')}
```

For any given input I want to create a list with two items where the first item is the value word and the second is the key word. For example, the expected output should be:

```
input: kitchen
output: ['kitchen','rooms']

input: bee
output: ['bee','insects']
```

I checked the question [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary) but afaict all answers work for dictionaries with 1 value per key.

I've tried the following naive, closed form code:

```
word=input('Enter a word: ')
word_pair=[]
word_pair.append(word)
if word in (words['seasons']):
    index=0
elif word in (words['rooms']):
    index=1
elif word in (words['insects']):
    index=2
else:
    index=3
try:
    key_val=list(words.keys())[index]
    word_pair.append(key_val)
except IndexError:
    word_pair.append('NA')

print(word_pair)
```

Obviously, this code only works for this specific dictionary as is. If I wanted to add a category, I'd have to add an elif clause. If I wanted to change the name of a category or their order, remove one, combine two or more, etc., I'd have to tweak a whole bunch of things by hand.

Is there a more generalized way to do this?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generator with unpacking:

```
inp = input()
result, *_ = ([inp, k] for k, v in words.items() if inp in v)
```

Even better to use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with generator, cause it will stop after first match found:

```
result = next([inp, k] for k, v in words.items() if inp in v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invert that dict with:

```
>>> {s_v:k for k,v in words.items() for s_v in v} 
{'summer': 'seasons', 'spring': 'seasons', 'autumn': 'seasons', 'winter': 'seasons', 'kitchen': 'rooms', 'loo': 'rooms', 'livingroom': 'rooms', 'hall': 'rooms', 'diningroom': 'rooms', 'bedroom': 'rooms', 'bee': 'insects', 'butterfly': 'insects', 'beetle': 'insects'}
```

And then lookup your input in the inverted dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```py
words={
    'seasons':('summer','spring','autumn','winter'),
    'rooms':('kitchen','loo','livingroom','hall','diningroom','bedroom'),
    'insects':('bee','butterfly','beetle')}

def find_cat(word):
    for category, items in words.items():
        if word in items:
            return category

word=input('Enter a word: ')

print(find_cat(word))
```

**Explanation:** `words.items()` return a tuple (key, value) for each key in the dictionary. In this case, value is a list. So, we can use the `in` operator to find if the `word` is in that list. If yes, simply return the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the dictionary keys:

```
words={
    'seasons':('summer','spring','autumn','winter'),
    'rooms':('kitchen','loo','livingroom','hall','diningroom','bedroom'),
    'insects':('bee','butterfly','beetle')}

search_text = input("input: ")

for key in words.keys():
    if search_text in words[key]:
        print("output: {0}".format([search_text,key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would test using `in` rather than exact match (see `word in value` in the code below), and you'd probably also want to include some kind of check that there is only one matching key, and provided that there is, use the first one.

```
words = {
    'seasons':('summer','spring','autumn','winter'),
    'rooms':('kitchen','loo','livingroom','hall','diningroom','bedroom'),
    'insects':('bee','butterfly','beetle')}

word = 'kitchen'

keys = [key for key, value in words.items() if word in value]

if len(keys) != 1:
    raise ValueError

word_pair = [word, keys[0]]

print(word_pair)
```

Gives:

```
['kitchen', 'rooms']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to transform your input dictionnary to inverse the logic: make values the keys, and the keys, values.

So a solution like [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491335/1290438):

```py
def invert_dic(index):
    new_dic = {}
    for k,v in index.items():
        for x in v:
            new_dic.setdefault(x,[]).append(k)
```

and then you'd do:

```py
index = invert_dic(words) # linear time, O(n)
word = input('Enter a word: ')
categories = index.get(word, ['None'])) # constant time, O(1)
print(', '.join(f"Your word is in those categories: {categories}")
```

That solution is mimicking the concept of indexes in databases, where you spend time at the creation of the database (the `words` dictionary being converted as the `index` dictionary) and memory to store that index, to have very fast resolution when looking up a word using the hash algorithm (where looking a key is in constant time).

A bonus of the above solution is that if a word is in two categories, you'll get the list of all the categories your word is in.