# Is there a dict + list comprehension way to do this?

Tags: python, list, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to solve the following problem using dict and list comprehension. Given

```
input = {"a":["b","c"], "d":["b","e"], "f":["g","c"]}
```

expected output is ::

```
output = {"b":["a","d"], "c":["a","f"], "e":["d"], "g":["f"]}
```

So far, I have only been able to come up with ::

```
output = {}
for (k,v) in input.items():
    for x in v:
        if x[0] not in output:
            output[x[0]] = [k]
        else:
            output[x[0]].append(k)
```

What would be a possible one line dict+list comprehension method to do this?

Comment: My 2 cents: refrain from the urge of one liners just for the sake of it

Comment: ugly way: `{v: [k for k in d if v in d[k]] for v in set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(input.values()))}`

Comment: The moderator mentions that this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491223/inverting-a-dictionary-with-list-values. 
However, the other question does not talk about dict+list comprehension

Comment: You can use the following code, unfortunatly I can't post this as an answer because the question is closed. `output_dict = {x:[key for (key, val) in input_dict.items() if x in val] for (k, v) in input_dict.items() for x in v}`