# Reverse a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to reverse a dictionary in Python

This is how it should work:

```
d={'move': ['liikuttaa'], 'hide': ['piilottaa', 'salata'], 'six': ['kuusi'], 'fir': ['kuusi']}
reverse_dictionary(d)
{'liikuttaa': ['move'], 'piilottaa': ['hide'], 'salata': ['hide'], 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```

Here is what I have come up with:

```
def reverse_dictionary(d):
    reversed = {value: key for (key, value) in d.items()}
    return reversed

def main():
    d = {'move': ['liikuttaa'], 'hide': ['piilottaa',
                                         'salata'], 'six': ['kuusi'], 'fir': ['kuusi']}
    print(reverse_dictionary(d))
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But since the value is in a list, the output results in a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Dictionary needs need to be immutable so you can use an integer, float, string, or Boolean as a dictionary key. However, list isn't immutable so you can't use it as a key.

Comment: Since each key in a dictionary is unique and hashable, each value must also be unique and hashable to reverse a dictionary.That's the reason you are getting this error.

Comment: Check this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491223/inverting-a-dictionary-with-list-values

Comment: I assume you mean a dictionary to reverse the translations?

Comment: @libby yup it's to reverse the translations but keep the list type the same

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def reverse_dictionary(d):
    reversed = defaultdict(list)
    for (key, array) in d.items():
        for value in array:
            reversed[value].append(key)
    return dict(reversed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just have to brute force it:

```
reversed = {}
for english,translated in translation.items():
  for word in translated:
    if word in reversed:
      reversed[word].append(english)
    else:
      reversed[word] = [english]
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or answering it? But yeah, it should technically work. as `hash(str([1,2,3]))` also works.

Answer (score 0):

```
newdict = {}

for key, val in d.items():
  if len(val) == 1:
     newdict[val[0]] = key
  else:
    for items in val:
       newdict[items] = key 

print(newdict)
```

One issue is that the last two will have the same key and you can't do that with a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I observe that your dictionary is of synonyms, translating words from English (**Language A**) to Finnish (detected language in google translator say **Language B**).

So what you need is reverse the translation: **Language B** to **Language A**.

---

### Case 1: Just reverse data structure without contextual meaning

If you simply put reverse the solution would not be dictionary which provides you translation at all.

i.e.
`"['piilottaa', 'salata']": "hide"`
or `"piilottaa, salata": "hide"` or `('piilottaa', 'salata')": "hide"`

If you are simply looking for solution like above, tuple could be great option to you, as tuple is immutable and can be dictionary key as well. ()

```
def reverse_dictionary(d):
    res = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        _val = tuple(value)
        res.setdefault(_val, []).append(key)
    return res
```

And your output would look like below:

```
{('liikuttaa',): ['move'],
 ('piilottaa', 'salata'): ['hide'],
 ('kuusi',): ['six', 'fir']}
```

---

### Case 2: Contextually reversing translation

on the other hand, if you actually wish your solution to be as reveres dictionary like `"piilottaa": ["hide"], "salata": ["hide"]` contextually as well, use this:

```
def reverse_contextual_dictionary(d):
    res = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        for _val in value:
            res.setdefault(_val, []).append(key)
    return res
```

And your output result would be as:

```
In [12]: d
Out[12]:
{'move': ['liikuttaa'],
 'hide': ['piilottaa', 'salata'],
 'six': ['kuusi'],
 'fir': ['kuusi']}

In [13]: reverse_contextual_dictionary(d)
Out[13]:
{'liikuttaa': ['move'],
 'piilottaa': ['hide'],
 'salata': ['hide'],
 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```